# Canvas Border HTML5

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, canvas

**Hello People**, I work on create html5 canvas project, I set canvas width equal to `$(window).width` and it's work well but the problems appear when I set border the horizontal scroll will be appear.

**Note:** I tried to use `innerWidth()` function but I have not yet found the right solution. Passion leads me to find out why this problem occurs.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('canvas').width($(window).width());
    $('canvas').height($(window).height());
    console.log($(window).width())

})
```

```css
* {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.home{
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
}
canvas{
    display:block;
    border:2px solid #0094ff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="home">
    <canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove this lines:

```
$('canvas').width($(window).width());
$('canvas').height($(window).height());
console.log($(window).width())
```

Set `width` and `height` with css:

```
canvas{
    display:block;
    border:2px solid #0094ff;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

used this css and script

css

```
 {
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
}
body{
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
}
.home{
width:100%;
height:auto;
}
canvas{
display:block;
border:2px solid #0094ff;
}
```

Script

```
$('canvas').width($(window).width() - 4);
$('canvas').height($(window).height() - 4);
console.log($(window).width());
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are using `.width` and `.height` you are setting sizes of content regardless `bos-sizing`. Replace them via `.css({width, height})`. Also remove `margin` of body and set canvas `display` to `block` to prevent vertical scroll.

By the way, you don't need to set sizes from the script, but possibly you do need to set diminsions.

```js
$(function () { // Only to set drawing scale of canvas, doesn't affect appearance
  var $window = $(window);
  var $canvas = $("canvas");
  var border = $canvas.css("border-width");
  
  $('canvas')
    .prop('width', $window.width() - 2 * border);
    .prop('height', $window.height() - 2 * border);
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body, canvas {
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

canvas{
  border: 2px solid #0094ff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
```